# Amazon Prime Video Bandwidth issue Error: 1060 on Sony Android TV

Tags: mtu

The Android TV Prime Video was not opening in our FTTH home broadband, it struck at welcome screen later with error display.

[image: Prime Video error opening]

Though we had 50 Mbps speed and average 30 ~ 40 Mbps, Prime Video app fail to open and showing Error code 1060. Insufficient bandwidth. But, the same was able to open on my Mobile hotspot of 4 Mbps, I was wondering what could be problem.

The bandwidth calculation need some improvement in App, the same TV Hotstar and other video player were able to pull the video on Android TV.

Comment: Please note this is a site for programming problems. This doesn’t seem to have anything to do with programming.

Comment: Its MTU based bandwidth calculation, I saw few post related to it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716021/difference-between-mtu-and-link-bandwidth

Comment: It’s still off topic here. Things that *may* have been on topic five years ago might not be today. It might work at Super User

Answer (score 0):

Further investigation found that Amazon App have hard method to handle the difference in MTU value between ONT Router and Home Router.

When MTU value set to 1492 both in ONT Router and Home Router, Prime Video able to open for playback. Earlier it was 1492 @ ONT Router and 1500 @ Home Router.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

did you check your internet speed, there are chances that your internet speed will be slow temporary.

Also check your internet bandwidth speed limit for streaming, you can take help from the google to change the bandwidth speed.

Try cable network
Restart Your Router
Reset Your Router
Disable Proxy Or VPN if using
at last contact amazon support

[Source](https://quaries.com/amazon-error-code-1060/)